# Access forbidden for some files locally on xampp , Windows

Tags: xampp, local

I have a folder which with index.html in it, this works fine, and images inside it work fine, but when i link to other files like css or js files and try and read them i get this error...

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Ive tried changing code in /conf/extra/httpd-xamp.conf 
...

```
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
```

to

```
    Deny From none
    Allow from all
```

but no luck,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was to do with the files being encrypted, they were in green text on windows.

This had nothing to do with XAMPP.